# $k+1$th marginal independent of $k$th marginal?

Tags: probability

Given a parameterized distribution over a $n$-dimensional space. For $k<n$, when is the $k+1$th marginal independent of the $k$th marginal? (In the sense that the covariance over the parameter space of $p_{k+1}$ and $p_{k}$ vanishes)